# visual studio command prompt is closing

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

i want to run visual studio(2010 or 2012) command prompt on `windows8` `x64`. but when i click on that(`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat`)  opening for few seconds and then closed. what is problem?

```
Edit:
```

it was `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat`

Comment: try running it directly from command prompt, that should prevent it from closing (at least to read the error message).

Comment: `vcvarsall.exe`??? Where did you find `vcvarsall.exe`? It has always been `vcvarsall.bat` and it is not "visual studio command prompt". Did something change in 2010 or 2012? Basically, the question is: why do you expect that `vcvarsall` to be "visual studio command prompt"?

Comment: sorry it was vcvarsall.bat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should start a Command Prompt (by clicking it in the Start menu or by running `cmd.exe`) and then run `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat` in that command prompt.

(If you just double-click a `.bat`, it will run and then the Command Prompt will close - that's normal Windows behaviour.)

Comment: thanks for your responce.ie cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC then type VCvcvarsall.bat in cmd?

Comment: Yes, or just type `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat` from wherever you are. The `TAB` key is your friend here.  :-)